Using IntelliJ with TeXiFy IDEA and proofreading by LanguageTool generates repeated whitespace warning around mintinline in Dutch
I'm trying out using IntelliJ with the TeXiFy plugin for writing my LaTeX documents.
So far I like it a lot, but I'm getting a lot of errors around my \mintinline commands. It seems it doesn't understand that mintinline will insert text and warns me that there will be two spaces after each other (there isn't).
Is there a way to let the LanguageTool know to consider the body of mintinline part of the flow of text? I assume it already does something similar for things in (for example) \emph{}.
While creating a MWE I noticed this problem only occurs when I write in Dutch.
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[newfloat]{minted}

\begin{document}

Een uitleg van het \mintinline{java}{abstract} keyword in java.

\end{document}



This is a known issue, I also asked about it on GitHub and got this reply: https://github.com/Hannah-Sten/TeXiFy-IDEA/issues/3621#issuecomment-2283214192
